# The meaning of the Dexter lock in the series Dexter

Tags: props, dexter

Every time the series started I remember wondering about the lock on Dexter's door. I was sure I had the same one in my garage so I went to check and it turned out to be a "Dexter" lock. Is there a specific meaning to this?

Comment: I think people here are misunderstanding the question. I thought the OP is talking about [**the actual Dexter lock**](http://consumer.schlage.com/products/pages/productdetails.aspx?ModelNumber=JD60619) (by Schlage) that looks like the character's apartment lock (though some people say it's actually a Defiant lock) and asked if there's any meaning behind this choice.

Comment: Yes Walt, that is what I meant. The lock has "Dexter" on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it did look pretty solid...

But no, I don't think there was a special meaning - apart from making Dexter's normal morning-ritual look "gruesome" by using weird camera-angles.

Also, remember that the whole opening credits - plus a bit extra - were shown in one of the episodes of the first season, to show that "life is good, and everything is great in Dexter's life"...  It was also parodied in a episode right after Dexter's son is born, and he's *extremely* sleep-deprived due to the baby - his t-shirt got baby-food/burp stains, his shoe-laces snaps, and he looks dead tired.

Answer (score 1):

I've always taken the opening credits of Dexter as a way of the producers to show that, on the surface at least, Dexter is a normal person.  He sleeps, wakes up, has breakfast, gets dressed and goes out.  Just like you or I would.

The showing of locking the door I'd always taken to mean that even when someone is a serial killer they don't take how dangerous they are for granted and assume people will know it's the home of a serial killer, and therefore they shouldn't break in.

Dexter is a normal guy with a normal routine.  The lock will be just a normal, everyday lock.

Why do they show this?  Because it's showing that Dexter is very careful to blend in with everyone else.  Don't stand out and don't give people a reason to remember you.

Answer (score 1):

Took several hundred tries... But persistence paid off.  Finally got the feed to stop on those few seconds where the lock is in the shot. I could read it and it said DEFIANT.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Whats-written-on-the-door-lock-of-Dexter%E2%80%99s-apartment